# Has extra always had two meanings

Tags: history

Extra as a prefix can mean apart from or outside of.

- extradition
- extraordinary
- extraneous
- extraterrestrial
- extradition

  [This site](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extra-) says it comes from the Latin extrā meaning outside of

However it can also mean 'more' or in addition to when used as a word.

- at no extra cost
- would you like any extra
- extra special

Is one of the uses newer than the other?

Comment: According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=extra) it's "probably (...) from shortenings of *extraordinary*, which in 18c. was used extensively as noun and adverb in places *extra* would serve today."

Comment: "At no extra cost" == "At no cost apart from the costs previously stated".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sources I've checked indicate that the word *extra* (not the prefix) is derived from "extraordinary". Obviously, that makes the prefix older. Since the very first time "extra" was used as a standalone word (apparently mid 1700s) it has meant "additional".

For example, the 1776 source [The philosophy of rhetoric](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zu5eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22extra+for+extraordinary.%22&source=bl&ots=iqy_VV0APS&sig=tXz2pdqix7Ck0XGqw4qWEZgYcbU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi56oLYiLTeAhWspYMKHTKrAocQ6AEwCHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22extra%20for%20extraordinary.%22&f=false) says:

> I shall just mention another set of barbarisms which also comes under this class, and arises from the abbreviation of polysyllables by lopping off all the syllables except the first or the first and second. Instances of this are *hyp* for *hypochondriac*, *rep* for *reputation*, *ult* for *ultimate*, *penult* for *penultimate*, *incog* for *incognito*, *hyper* for *hypercritic*, ***extra* for *extraordinary***. Happily all these affected terms have been denied the public suffrage. The humour of abbreviating now hardly subsists among us and requires no particular notice.

The sense of extraordinary that this refers to is now obsolete. It is defined in the OED as:

> Additional to, over and above what is usual; = *extra* adj.   Often following the noun; in which case the adjective cannot always be distinguished from the adverb. *Obsolete.*

"Extraordinary" in this sense dates back to at least the mid 1600s according to the OED.

[This 1737 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ieY2AQAAMAAJ&dq=%22extra%22+the&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22extra%22), for example refers to both "charges extra<sup>ry</sup>" and "charges extra.", where both are clearly abbreviations for *extraordinary* in this sense.